# Gradle: startscript classpath

Tags: gradle

I want to create runnable scripts for a jar. I have a config folder under the root which is not in the classpath and need to add this to the startScripts task.

Layout:

```
 - src/main/java
 - src/main/resources
 - config
```

If I try adding the folder like this:

```
startScripts {
    applicationName = 'Example'
    mainClassName = "com.abc.Main"
    classpath  += files('$APP_HOME/config/*')
}
```

However the folder `APP_HOME/lib/config` is added in the bash script, but not `config`.

Comment: Have you tried adding the "config" directory to your processResources task's inputs?